# jQuery show/hide div on select change not working with JSON populated options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have some options that I am adding to a web form and to clean up the HTML a bit I am using some scripts to populate the options for some of the select boxes. I need to show/hide some divs based on what is selected and it is working correctly for one of the selects that has the hardcoded HTML options. However, for the other dropdown that I am populating via a script and some JSON it is not showing or hiding the div on change. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gMS7/)

if you choose member +1 guest then the one div shows as it should. But the other never shows the other div!

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="tickets">
  <label for="group1">Number of Tickets: <span class="req">*</span></label>
  <select class="group1_dropdown" id="group1" name="group1">
   <option value="0">-- Please select --</option>
   <option value="1">Member</option>
   <option value="2">Member + 1 Guest</option>
   <option value="3">Member + 2 Guests</option>
   <option value="4">Member + 3 Guests</option>
  </select>
 <label class="visuallyhidden">Year</label>
 <select id="yearSelectionBox2" class="stringInfoSpacing">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Year</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div id="payMethod">
  <div class="header"> PAYMENT METHOD </div>
   <div id="payOptions">
    <div id="payInfo">
    <div id="pay0" class="paymentinfo">
    <p>PAYMENT INFO OPTION 1</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="pay222" class="tacos">
  <p>Years Data</p>
 </div>
```

Here are the scripts I am using:

```
 var YearListItems2= "";
for (var i = 0; i < modelYearJsonList2.modelYearTable2.length; i++){
YearListItems2+= "<option value='" + modelYearJsonList2.modelYearTable2[i].modelYearID + "'>" + modelYearJsonList2.modelYearTable2[i].modelYear + "</option>";
  };
    $("#yearSelectionBox2").html(YearListItems2); 
     //The div is not showing/hiding as it should 
     $("#yearSelectionBox2").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      str = parseInt($("select option:selected").val());       
     if(str == 2013)
     $("#pay222").show('slow');
      else
         $("#pay222").hide('fast');
 });
 //This one works as it should
  $("#group1").change(function () {
   var str = "";
  str = parseInt($("select option:selected").val());       
   if(str == 2)
     $("#payMethod").show('slow');
     else
      $("#payMethod").hide('fast');
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select element selector is wrong in the change event handlers, `this` refers to the select element that was changed use that to refer to the element instead of using another selector

```
$("#yearSelectionBox2").change(function () {
    var str = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (str == 2013) {
        $("#pay222").show('slow');
    } else {
        $("#pay222").hide('fast');
    }
});
```

You have used `$("select option:selected")` to get the selected value, which will always return the value of the first select element instead of the current one, use `$(this).value()` instead.

Note: The same mistake is there in the `group1` handler also, it is working now because that is the first select in the given page now, when a new select is added before that this will fail.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you Arun.

Answer (score 1):

Your select element selector is wrong. Either you should use `$(this)` or `select element id`(becuase id's will be unique).

```
$("#yearSelectionBox2").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str = parseInt($(this).val());        
     if(str == 2013)
         $("#pay222").show('slow');
      else
          $("#pay222").hide('fast');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5gMS7/2/)**

or

```
$("#yearSelectionBox2").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str = parseInt($("select#yearSelectionBox2 option:selected").val());        
     if(str == 2013)
         $("#pay222").show('slow');
      else
          $("#pay222").hide('fast');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5gMS7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

In your code just change

This line :

```
str = parseInt($("select option:selected").val());
```

To:

```
str = parseInt($("select#yearSelectionBox2 option:selected").val());
```